# Convert time string into timestamp/date time in scala

Tags: scala, datetime, user-defined-functions, datetime-format, time-format

I am receiving time data into my source as a csv file in the format (HHMMSSHS). I am not sure about what HS in the format stands for. example data will be like 15110708.

I am creating table in databricks table with received columns and data. I want to convert this field to time while processing in scala.
I am using UDF to do formating on any data on the go. But for this i am totally stuck while writing a UDF for parsing only time.

The final output should be 15:11:07:08 or any time format suitable for this string.

I tried with java.text.SimpleDateFormat and faced issue with unparsable string.

Is there any way to convert the above given string to a time format?

I am storing this value as acolumn in databricks notebook table. Is there any other format other than string to save only time values?

Comment: Can you sahre some code ?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I would suppose HS is for hundredths of seconds. BTW `SimpleDateFormat` doesn’t support those. java.time does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried?:

```
import java.time.LocalTime

val dtf : DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssSS")
  
val localTime = udf { str : String =>
  LocalTime.parse(str, dtf).toString
}
```

that gives:

```
+---------+------------+
|Timestamp|converted   |
+---------+------------+
|15110708 |15:11:07.080|
|15110708 |15:11:07.080|
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: I tried the same, but the issue is I am creating table in databricks and if the datatype for this time is string then its fine, But if I want to use datatype (date/timestamp) how could i use it.

Comment: Is there any data type other than string(date/timestamp) in that we can show only time.

Comment: I tried with date type, its giving null as output
I tried with timestamp, it is giving current date in the output along with this time value

Comment: There is no SparkSQL type to deal only with times